# How to trigger same event on every page of the WPF App using MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

Our application is implemented in WPF using MVVM Light.

We are replacing our old magnetic card reader which is currently a serial one with a USB HID-KB. 
Serial card reader were easy since we had serial port events to trigger the incoming messages, we had no problem in handling these. But with USB card reader, the events are that of a normal keyboard.  By the way, the card reader does not have vendor specific API, this a generic USB device.

As of now the solution is to capture a keydownevent in the view and handle the business logic on the viewmodel.

But the problem here is that the end user can swipe the card irrespective on whatever page he/she is on. We should be able to capture that swipe event. The only option I currently have is that I need to wire this keydownevent on every view as mentioned above.

Is there any way in MVVMLight or WPF that can declare an event on the global level, that can be triggered from every view.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple.
Why don’t you handle the event in a common file, like the base file. Normally we handle application close events in such base files which will always be active. The thing is I have some conditions to check while the application is closing. So I handle the event in the common base file and do the condition checking there.

Please try that and let me know the result..

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the problem here is not with the handler, I have already added it in the viewmodelbase class, I need a way to add the event. The only way that I am currently aware is to add it in every view.

Comment: Why you want to handle in every view? Do you have to display the data in current view. 
I was saying if you handle it in the main xaml.cs file. ie the main view file which contains other views, irrespective of the view, you can get the event in one place.

Comment: We do not have a main view which is containing all the other views, every view is on its own.

Comment: Then you can't do globally. Or else there should be a common control in each and every view like a header or something. If there is something like that, then you can handle the event in that class commonly.